# Desired State Configuration credential private key not acquired

Tags: powershell, certificate, public-key, dsc

I'm trying to use powershell DSC for a few things. I wanted to have the passed credentials encrypted per the instructions at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn781430.aspx it all seems to work fine until I run start-DscConfiguration on the target node and i get the error:

> The private key could not be acquired.
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (root/Microsoft/...gurationManager:String) [], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 1
>       + PSComputerName        : DmitriyDev

Going back I checked to see that the mof contains the credentials encrypted and the meta.mof contains the matching thumbprint, etc.

going back to the original article i see the example code:

> ```
> # Get the certificate that works for encryption 
> function Get-LocalEncryptionCertificateThumbprint 
> { 
>     (dir Cert:\LocalMachine\my) | %{ 
>                     # Verify the certificate is for Encryption and valid 
>                     if ($_.PrivateKey.KeyExchangeAlgorithm -and $_.Verify()) 
>                     { 
>                         return $_.Thumbprint 
>                     } 
>                 } 
> }
> ```

When I test my certificate using this code (on the target node) I see that the PrivateKey of the certificate is null. I'm not sure how the certificate is null. Trying a few things with certutil and the technique mentioned http://blogs.technet.com/b/vishalagarwal/archive/2010/03/30/verifying-the-private-key-property-for-a-certificate-in-the-store.aspx it seems that I do indeed have a private key, however Powershell see it only as null.

On the target node, I even exported the public private key manually and reimported them, with no luck as outlined in another dsc tutorial.

I also tried using procmon to see what the problem was on the target node. I see the wmiprvse process and see that it runs as System (as expected), and I checked to make sure that the permissions on the private key allowed for system (all on the target node)

So my question is how do I get my private key to be used by DSC specifically the LCM on the target node? Or how do I diagnose the problem more?

Comment: Is the certificate held on your account or against the `system` account?  Maybe try running this lookup under the current user's credentials (`[System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials`); i.e. so it looks within that account's certificate store.  Not sure though as I've not played with certificates...

Comment: it's a machine certificate, because the DSC Local Configuration Manager runs under the System account AFAIK (hence the need to pass credentials for any network activity)

Comment: Please clarify which computer you are referring to in every part of your question. There should be 2 computers involved: the node (the computer onto which configuration will apply), and one where you generate the MOF (let's call it the generator). The generator does not need the certificate installed. It only needs the public key portion available on the file system during generation. The *node* however, must have the certificate installed with the private key. See if [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/632390/protecting-credentials-in-desired-state-configuration-using-certificates) helps.

Comment: Briantist, I actually had read your linked to article previously, and in general I followed the same pattern. I created a template based on the workstation auth template and used that on to the target node. It all seemed to work, but powershell doesn't seem to see the private key on the target node. I saw something similar at [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vishalagarwal/archive/2010/03/30/verifying-the-private-key-property-for-a-certificate-in-the-store.aspx).

Comment: Interesting; I think I'm using the Computer template for autoenrollment (or least a template cloned from it). Glad you got it worked out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar error when using New-SelfSignedCertificate to create my certificates. For anyone with similar issues, I suspect the problem is related to the storage provider used by New-SelfSignedCertificate (see http://blogs.technet.com/b/vishalagarwal/archive/2010/03/30/verifying-the-private-key-property-for-a-certificate-in-the-store.aspx, which talks about a problem with the Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider and .NET classes). There's a powershell script available on [technet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Self-signed-certificate-5920a7c6) that creates self-signed certificates, and defaults to using a different storage provider, which solved the problem for me.

Comment: In my case, it was the Get-PfxData cmdlet that apparently caused the Microsoft Software KSP (CNG) to be used instead of the Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider (CryptoAPI), as in the original certificate. (I used Get-PfxData | Export-PfxCertificate to change the password on the pfx file.)

Comment: you are correct, it does seem to be a problem with CNG and .net as further described here: http://www.hyper-v.nu/archives/bgelens/2015/02/integrating-vm-role-with-desired-state-configuration-part-7-creating-a-configuration-document-with-encrypted-content/
use computer as the template as it defaults to the legacy provider.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i'm not sure exactly *why* this works, but it does. Using the Computer template seems to work. In terms of work, powershell on the target node can see it's private key from

> dir cert:\LocalMachine\My | ? PrivateKey -ne $null

Once that happens it all works as expected. So long story short is don't use the workstation Auth template but the Computer template.